# Edit posts in a Telegram channel after 1 hour using API (PHP)

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

Is there a way to automatically edit posts in a channel using a bot after 1 hour?

For example, I want this message:

**This is my Ad**

**call me: 2000**

Changed to this message after 1 hour:

**This is my Ad**

**Expired**

Answer (score 1):

Read section [Updating messages](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#updating-messages) in telegram documentation.